# Drupal 8 - page.html.twig not updating website

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal, and I'm creating a custom theme based on a [Bootstrap Bario](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio) subtheme on Drupal 8.
I can update the CSS with no problem, but I first need to clear the cache before reloading the page (which gets annoying, is there a way to avoid that?).

This is how the theme's regions are arranged:

[image: Regions Layout]

I added the `help: 'Help'` region in the *.info.yml* file, under the line `footer_fifth: 'Footer Fifth'`, and the added Help region appears in the Block Layout page.

I then modified the relevant parts of *templates/_page.html.twig* like so:
From this

```
{% block footer %}
<div class="{{ container }}">
  {% if page.footer_first or page.footer_second or page.footer_third or page.footer_fourth %}
    <div class="site-footer__top clearfix">
      {{ page.footer_first }}
      {{ page.footer_second }}
      {{ page.footer_third }}
      {{ page.footer_fourth }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if page.footer_fifth %}
    <div class="site-footer__bottom">
      {{ page.footer_fifth }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

to this

```
{% block footer %}
<div class="{{ container }}">
  {% if page.footer_first or page.footer_second or page.footer_third or page.footer_fourth or page.footer_fifth %}
    <div class="site-footer__top clearfix">
      {{ page.footer_first }}
      {{ page.footer_second }}
      {{ page.footer_third }}
      {{ page.footer_fourth }}
      {{ page.footer_fifth }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if page.help %}
    <div class="site-footer__bottom">
      {{ page.help }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I added `or page.footer_fifth` to the first `if` statement, moved  `{{ page.footer_fifth }}` to the `site-footer__top` div, and added `{{ page.help }}` in its place.

After that, I go and clear the cache, but the block regions are still the same. If I inspect my block in the Footer Fifth region, it is still in the `<div class="site-footer__bottom">`.
Did I miss something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the template file name is wrong. See:

templates/_page.html.twig usually should be:

templates/page.html.twig

the complete path of your template should be "/themes/custom/yourthemename/".

PS: theme debug will help you in case of any doubt.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates

Comment: Can't believe that was the problem... Thank you so much